# How to join with multiple instances of a model when using a join table with active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, subquery, inner-join

This is for Rails 5 / Active Record 5 using PostgreSQL.

Let's say I have two models: `Product` and `Widget`. A `Product` `has_many` widgets and a `Widget` `has_many` products via a join table called `products_widgets`.

I want to write a query that finds all products that are associated with *both* the widget with `id=37` *and* the widget with `id=42`.

I actually have a list of ids, but if I can write the above query, I can solve this problem in general.

Note that the easier version of this query is to find all widgets that are associated with *either* the widget with `id=37` *or* the widget with `id=42`, which you could write as follows:

`Product.joins(:products_widgets).where(products_widgets: {widget_id: [37, 42]})`

But that isn't what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a starter: in pure SQL, you could phrase the query with `exists` conditions:

```
select p.*
from product p
where 
    exists (
        select 1 
        from products_widgets pw 
        where pw.product_id = p.product_id and pw.widget_id = 37
    )
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from products_widgets pw 
        where pw.product_id = p.product_id and pw.widget_id = 42
    )
```

In active Record, we can try and use the raw subqueries directly in `where` conditions:

```
product
    .where('exists(select 1 from products_widgets where product_id = product.product_id and widget_id = ?)', 37)
    .where('exists(select 1 from products_widgets where product_id = product.product_id and widget_id = ?)', 42)
```

I think that using `.arel.exist` might also work:

```
product
    .where(products_widgets.where('product_id = product.product_id and widget_id = ?', 37).arel.exists)
    .where(products_widgets.where('product_id = product.product_id and widget_id = ?', 42).arel.exists)
```

Comment: this is really helpful -- just a side note, what are the indexing requirements for this sort of strategy to be performant? Do I need an "exists" index for that exact query or should my existing indexes on the id columns be sufficient?

Comment: @SamJohnson: for this query, I would recommend an index on `products_widgets(product_id, widget_id)`, so the `exists` subqueries can execute fast (but maybe it is already in place).